# What do abrupt price fluctuations mean for a stock?

Tags: stocks

One example brought to the question is the case of the pharmaceutics company Mylan that completed the merger with a Pfizer division and Upjohn to form Viatris(VTRS) on November 15 approx.

What does a steep decline and recovery mean? That period variation was **2.10**$-24.88$
-What has happened from Nov 10 to Nov 17?
-And why did it reach a higher than normal peak(24.88$)on Nov 13?
[image: see graphic]

Comment: It is likely that you are looking at bad data.  Your picture is a graph of which security?

Comment: It likely means nothing. Google's stock graphs are far from perfect. Seek out a more reliable graph.

Comment: yes,my bad. Its not precise data.